# Transition from sizewithFont:constrainedToSize:lineBreakMode: for iOS 7 not behaving as expected

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios7

I'm trying to get rid of functions that have been deprecated in iOS 7, and I'm running it something that I don't understand. Here's the code I have right now:

```
CGFloat titleHeight = [[object name] sizeWithFont:[UIFont fontWithName:@"Abel" size:24.0f] constrainedToSize:CGSizeMake(170.0f, 200.0f) lineBreakMode:NSLineBreakByWordWrapping].height;
NSMutableParagraphStyle *paragraphStyle = [NSMutableParagraphStyle new];
paragraphStyle.lineBreakMode = NSLineBreakByWordWrapping;
CGFloat titleHeight2 = [[object name] boundingRectWithSize:CGSizeMake(170.0f, 200.0f) options:0 attributes:@{NSFontAttributeName: [UIFont fontWithName:@"Abel" size:24.0f], NSParagraphStyleAttributeName: paragraphStyle}  context:nil].size.height;
```

For some reason, `titleHeight` and `titleHeight2` end up being different values, and I can't figure out why. Any ideas? Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The documentation [says](https://developer.apple.com/library/iOS/documentation/UIKit/Reference/NSString_UIKit_Additions/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSString/boundingRectWithSize%3aoptions%3aattributes%3acontext%3a):

> To correctly draw and size multi-line text, pass
>   [`NSStringDrawingUsesLineFragmentOrigin`](https://developer.apple.com/library/iOS/documentation/UIKit/Reference/NSAttributedString_UIKit_Additions/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/c/econst/NSStringDrawingUsesLineFragmentOrigin) in the options parameter.

Have you tried that?

Comment: I missed that in the docs! Thanks! Will accept once SO lets me

Comment: Nah, I have .size.height at the end of the line.

Comment: Also, no need for the NSMutableParagraphStyle either, that option took care of the problem.

Comment: @Mason, Got that. My bad.